Any way to lock the keyboard and mouse on the host computer when streaming a game on Steam?
I sometimes play games by streaming to my laptop from my PC, however, sometimes my cat is in the room (and I am not) and when he sees things on the monitor, he jumps on the table and press keys or nudge the mouse around.
I know I can just turn off my monitor but that's only half the battle as my cat just sometimes jumps on the table regardless if there's anything on display. Unplugging the keyboard and mouse every time is a hassle.
So I was wondering if there's some kind of software I can use or an AutoHotKey script that can disable the physical mouse and keyboard when a game is streaming. I don't want to block inputs in general because that might interfere with sending inputs via in-home streaming so I just the hardware keyboard and mouse disabled.

For the keyboard, there is this application.  It was originally as an AutoHotKey script turned into an executable.  Conveniently, they also include the AutoHotKey script in the .zip, so you can either run the script yourself, or just run the executable.  I've tested it (the executable), and it seems to work fine.  Simply type Ctrl + Alt + L and it will disable nearly everything except a few key combinations as mentioned on that site.  To unlock your keyboard, type "unlock".
The script is:
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; THE KEYBOARD LOCKER                                       ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; This script will disable the keyboard when the user       ;
; presses Ctrl+Alt+L. The keyboard is reenabled if the user ;
; types in the string "unlock".                             ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Originally written by Lexikos:                            ;
;  http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/post-147849.html#147849  ;
; Modifications by Trevor Bekolay for the How-To Geek       ;
;  http://www.howtogeek.com/                                ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

#Persistent
FileInstall, enabled.ico, enabled.ico, 0
FileInstall, disabled.ico, disabled.ico, 0
Init()

ToggleTray:
  ToggleTray()
return

Exit:
  ExitApp
return

; This can only execute if the keyboard is NOT blocked,
; so it can't be used to unblock the keyboard.
^!l::
  KeyWait, Ctrl ; don't block Ctrl key-up
  KeyWait, Alt  ; or Alt key-up
  KeyWait, l    ; or l-up
  BlockKeyboard()
return

Init()
{
  global notray = 0
  Menu, Tray, Icon, enabled.ico
  Menu, Tray, NoStandard
  Menu, Tray, Tip, Press Ctrl+Alt+L to lock your keyboard
  Menu, Tray, Add, Hide tray notifications, ToggleTray
  Menu, Tray, Add, Exit, Exit
  TrayTip,,To lock your keyboard press Ctrl+Alt+L.,10,1
}

ToggleTray()
{
  global notray
  
  if (notray = 0) {
    notray = 1
    Menu, Tray, Rename, Hide tray notifications, Show tray notifications
  } else {
    notray = 0
    Menu, Tray, Rename, Show tray notifications, Hide tray notifications
  }
}

BlockKeyboard(block=-1) ; -1, true or false.
{
  static hHook = 0, cb = 0
  global notray
  
  if !cb ; register callback once only.
    cb := RegisterCallback("BlockKeyboard_HookProc")
 
  if (block = -1) ; toggle
    block := (hHook=0)
 
  if ((hHook!=0) = (block!=0)) ; already (un)blocked, no action necessary.
    return
 
  if (block) {
    if (notray = 0) {
      ; Show TrayTip to remind user of unlock string
      TrayTip,
        ,Your keyboard is now locked.`nType in "unlock" to unlock it.
        ,10,1
    }

    Menu, Tray, Icon, disabled.ico ; Change tray icon
    Menu, Tray, Tip, Type "unlock" to unlock your keyboard
    hHook := DllCall("SetWindowsHookEx"
      , "int", 13  ; WH_KEYBOARD_LL
      , "uint", cb ; lpfn (callback)
      , "uint", 0  ; hMod (NULL)
      , "uint", 0) ; dwThreadId (all threads)
  }
  else {
    if (notray = 0) {
      TrayTip,
        ,Your keyboard is now unlocked.`nPress Ctrl+Alt+L to lock it again.
        ,10,1
    }
    
    Menu, Tray, Icon, enabled.ico ; Change tray icon
    Menu, Tray, Tip, Press Ctrl+Alt+L to lock your keyboard
    DllCall("UnhookWindowsHookEx", "uint", hHook)
    hHook = 0
  }
}

BlockKeyboard_HookProc(nCode, wParam, lParam)
{
    static count = 0
    
    ; Unlock keyboard if "unlock" typed in
    if (NumGet(lParam+8) & 0x80) { ; key up
      if (count = 0 && NumGet(lParam+4) = 0x16) {        ; 'u'
        count = 1
      } else if (count = 1 && NumGet(lParam+4) = 0x31) { ; 'n'
        count = 2
      } else if (count = 2 && NumGet(lParam+4) = 0x26) { ; 'l'
        count = 3
      } else if (count = 3 && NumGet(lParam+4) = 0x18) { ; 'o'
        count = 4
      } else if (count = 4 && NumGet(lParam+4) = 0x2E) { ; 'c'
        count = 5
      } else if (count = 5 && NumGet(lParam+4) = 0x25) { ; 'k'
        count = 0
        BlockKeyboard(false)
      } else {
        count = 0
      }
    }

    return 1
}

For the mouse, I also found this AutoHotKey (version 2) script.  Press F to disable your mouse (clicks, movement, and wheel), and Ctrl + C to enable it again.  You can modify the script to change those keys as you wish obviously.
; This script blocks mouse movement, mouse buttons, and wheel
#Requires AutoHotkey v2.0
BlockTheMouse := False

f:: {
 Global BlockTheMouse := True
 BlockInput 'MouseMove'
 SoundBeep 1500
}

^c:: {
 Global BlockTheMouse:= False
 BlockInput 'MouseMoveOff'
 SoundBeep 1000
}

#HotIf BlockTheMouse
LButton::
RButton::
MButton::
XButton1::
XButton2::
WheelUp::
WheelDown::
WheelLeft::
WheelRight::Return
#HotIf

The only issue here is, the first script is AutoHotKey version 1, while the second script is version 2.  So you'll need both versions of AutoHotKey installed, which I believe is fine, but a bit annoying.  I would probably run the .exe for the keyboard locker, and the script to disable the mouse so I wouldn't have to have an outdated version of AutoHotKey installed.
